# Script to add an operator on to an existing SQLServer job

Tags: sql

Would you please let me know a script which enables an existing operator to be added onto SQL agent job?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `My Operator` set up, the following will alert that operator by Email on job failure. You can change @notify_level_email to the condition you desire

[sp_update_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
USE [msdb];

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='My Job', 
    @notify_level_email=2, /* notify on failure */
    @notify_email_operator_name=N'My Operator';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would you update the operator to be blank if it’s no longer required please?